# Multi-particle state in relativistic quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, perturbation-theory

I was following lecture notes of Sidney coleman (https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.5013)(page 7) where he stated:

> "The addition of relativity is necessary at energies $E \geq m c^{2}$. At these energies
> $$
> p+p \rightarrow p+p+\pi^{0}
> $$
> is possible. At slightly higher energies
> $$
> p+p \rightarrow p+p+p+\bar{p}
> $$
> can occur. The exact solution of a high energy scattering problem necessarily involves many particle processes.
>
> You might think that for a given $E,$ only a finite number, even a small number, of processes actually contribute, but you already know from NRQM that that isn't true.
> $$
> H \rightarrow H+\delta V \quad \delta E_{0}=\langle 0|\delta V| 0\rangle+\sum_{n} \frac{|\langle 0|\delta V| n\rangle|^{2}}{E_{0}-E_{n}}+\cdots\tag{1}
> $$
> Intermediate states of all energies contribute, suppressed by energy denominators. For calculations of high accuracy effects at low energy, relativistic effects of order $(v / c)^{2}$ can be included. Intermediate states with extra particles will contribute corrections of order
> $$\frac{E}{m c^{2}} = \frac{\text{Typical energies in problem}}{\text{Typical energy denominator}} \sim \frac{m v^{2}}{m c^{2}}=\left(\frac{v}{c}\right)^{2}\tag{2}$$
>
> As a general conclusion: the corrections of relativistic kinematics and the corrections from multiparticle intermediate states are comparable; the addition of relativity forces you to consider many-body problems. "

I have the following doubts regarding this paragraph:

1. How does the equation 1 and 2 related? Precisely why do we consider only the kinetic energy for the numerator(for interaction part in the perturbation expression) while the rest mass energy $mc^2$ for the energy denominator?

My thinking goes as follows: For any pair production En-E0>mc^2 hence the factor in the denominator. Am I right?